# Android Fragment reload after onclick

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using the material design tabs. I have different fragment on each tab. In one fragment I have edit Text and button and bellow is list view. ListView is populate from api and also message is create using the api(POST).

After user click on the createMessageBtn it create the message to server. But not update the listview after on click event is occur. Until Fragment Message tab not reload the newly created message not showing. When I move to different tabs and then again came to message tab then newly created message is in the listView. I want to update the listview after the createMessageBtn clicked or reload the fragment.

Here is fragment_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Create Message"
            android:id="@+id/createMessagelbl"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/createMessagetxt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createMessagelbl"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ff7e7e7e"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Post"
            android:id="@+id/createMessagebtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createMessagetxt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:textColor="#ff4a8aff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/top" android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/messagesListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>/

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here Message Fragment.java

```
public class Message extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    private ArrayList<Messages> mMessagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MessagesListAdapter mAdapter;

    ListView mListView;
    EditText mMessageText;
    Button mMessagePostBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMessages();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.messagesListView);
        mMessageText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.createMessagetxt);
        mMessagePostBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.createMessagebtn);
        mMessagePostBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mMessagesList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    private void getMessages() {
        String URL ="Url";
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            // Here I am adding the result to mMessagesList

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mAdapter.setData(mMessageList);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

            // Here is my token
            String token = "Token " + getToken;

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", token);
                return headers;
            }
        };


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.createMessagebtn:

                if (mMessageText.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    mMessageText.setError("Please Enter the Message");

                } else {
                    String url = "Url";
                    postMessage(url, mMessageText.getText().toString());
                    mMessageText.setText("");
                    getMessages();

                    /*FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    MessagesFragment messageFragment = new MessagesFragment();
                    ft.detach(messageFragment);
                    ft.attach(messageFragment);
                    ft.commit();*/

                }
        }
    }


    public void postMessage(String url, final String message) {

        ToastMessage.showToastMessage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), message);
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        // Here Message is post Successfully

                        getMessages();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        ) {

           // Here is my token
            String token = "Token " + getToken;

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {

                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("message", message);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  header = new HashMap<String, String>();
                header.put("Authorization", token);
                return header;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
    }

}
```

Here is my PageAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Some", "Some", "Some","Messages", "Some" };
    private Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                SomeFragment some = new SomeFragment ();
                return some ;
            case 1:
                SomeFragment some = new SomeFragment ();
                return market;
            case 2:
                SomeFragment some = new SomeFragment ();
                return some ;
            case 3:
                MessagesFragment messages = new MessagesFragment();
                return messages;
            case 4:
                SomeFragment some = new SomeFragment ();
                return some ;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Here MessageListAdapter.java

```
public class MessagesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Messages> messagesItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MessagesListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Messages> messagesItems) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.messagesItems = messagesItems;
    }


    public void setData(ArrayList<Messages> messagesItems) {
        this.messagesItems = messagesItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return messagesItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messagesItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (mInflater == null)
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_list_row, null);

        //here my view from xml files

        Messages m = messagesItems.get(position);

        //here My populate xml file with data

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: try putting `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`after wherever you use getMessages()

Comment: Also i don't see you changing `mMessagesList` after you post  and get new messages, your ListView uses `mMessagesList`and you need to provide it with new list items

Comment: Inside the postMessage on volley success response i have call getMessage method and inside the getMessage on volley success reponse I add the all items in the mMessagesList. so mMessageList is updated it has the updated data

Comment: you can make setData(newlist) function inside MessagesListAdapter which updates array of items with new items inside adapter. Then in getMessage() you call `mAdapter.setData(newArray);` and`mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: why i need setData method inside the MessageListAdapter. Inside the MessageListAdpater constructor i have passed the mMessageList.

Comment: since you changed you mMessageList, ListView cant see your new added items, so you need to update mMessageList after you add new items

Comment: I think in messageListAdapter constructor I have pass mMessageList. Wheneve i called getMessages it will update the listview. I also add the method like you said but still same. I using viewpager one activity has different fragment on each tab. I have to reload the MessageFragment after onlcik event occur on mCreateMessageBtn?

Comment: I have add the MessageListAdapter.java please see if any mistake please correct me